# Android - Fitting bitmap to screen

Tags: android, bitmap, height, width, landscape

I have this project in which I have a bitmap bigger than the screen size. I want to resize it to fit the screen exactly. I have no titlebar, and I am in fullscreen mode. This is my non-working code:

```
public class ScopView extends View
{
    private Scop thescop;

    public ScopView(Context context, Scop newscop)
    {
        super(context);
        this.thescop = newscop;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Bitmap scopeBitmap;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfOptions.inDither = false;
        bfOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        bfOptions.inInputShareable = true;
        bfOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];

        scopeBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.scope, bfOptions);
        scopeBitmap.createScaledBitmap(scopeBitmap, SniperActivity.Width, SniperActivity.Height, false);
        canvas.drawBitmap(scopeBitmap, SniperActivity.scopx, SniperActivity.scopy, null);
    }
}
```

While in here the createScaledBitmap method, I am using itself as the source, and some variables from an activity used to retrieve the window height and width from screen preferences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the below code to resize the bitmap.

```
int h = 320; // Height in pixels
int w = 480; // Width in pixels    
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(largeBitmap, h, w, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use the below code snippet.

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // Create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // Resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // Recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is help to you try this

```
int REQ_WIDTH = 0;
int REQ_HEIGHT = 0;
REQ_WIDTH =imageView.getWidth();
vREQ_HEIGHT =imageView.getHeight();
mImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageURI, options), REQ_HEIGHT, REQ_WIDTH, true));
```